# Will heavy rain tomorrow be a problem if I pour concrete today?

Tags: concrete, driveway

If I start pouring concrete **today** at 2PM while it's sunny, and it starts to rain heavily **tomorrow** at 2PM... and not stop raining for the next 5 days (this is the weather forecast), will my driveway be fine?

Is 20+ hours enough time for the concrete to harden and not get "dug up" by heavy rain?

Answer (score 3):

No, it isn't a problem if...

1. You lay poly sheeting or a tarp over it after several hours of cure time (ideally the following morning). Driving rain could degrade the surface of the slab, which is still soft even after a day.
2. Water running along the slab won't undermine its base.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your concrete sets up normally, it should be fine if it rains 20+ hours later.  I've done it several times with no problems.  It would only be a problem if there is something stopping it from setting up, like freezing weather.